# Show that the Galois extension $\cong H\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $E\subset \mathbb{C}$ be the splitting field of $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\sqrt{-d}\in E$, for a positive integer $d$. Show that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}) \cong H\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ for some group $H$. [Hint: Use complex conjugation]

My attempt:

In order to use Galois correspondence, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})\subset E$. If $d$ is not a square, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$ and hence $E$ has a subextension of order $4$ and hence $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ must have a subgroup of order 2. I'm not sure how to go further to use complex conjugation and if I need to construct the explicit homomorphism involved in the definition of the semidirect product. Thanks.

Comment: If $d$ is not a square, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the stabiliser of $\sqrt{-d}$ in $G$, and $\sigma$ denote the
operation of complex conjugation. Then $H$ has index $2$ in $G=\text{Gal}(E/\Bbb Q)$ and $\sigma\notin H$. Moreover $\langle\sigma\rangle$ is normal in $G$.
All of these combine to prove that $G$ is a semidirect product of $H$ and
$\langle\sigma\rangle$.

Comment: I think you wanted to state that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$? $\langle\sigma\rangle$ usually isn't. Consider $E=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\sqrt{-3})$ as an example. If both were normal you would get a direct product.